# Row count between specific value - sql

Tags: sql, count, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I using Snowflake,
i'm trying to find out what is the simplest way to count the amount of rows in a column,
between one specific value to its next appearance.
to make thing simple, lets assume this value is 1 , while all the rest are 0.
I have tried several window functions,
(mostly UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) but the result was not as I expected.

[image]

the upper table is the original data set,
and the second one is the expected result.
Thank you for your assistance,

Comment: How are you ordering the rows? From the data supplied there appears to be no way of consistently ordering the rows and, if you can’t do that, your question is unanswerable

Comment: HI can you explain how you are getting the values under the column "rows per entry" ?

Comment: @HimanshuKandpal by counting the rows between the current “1” row and the previous “1” row - or the start of the dataset

Answer (score 0):

So the normal way I solve this is to map the data to group buckets the data first:

```
with data (id, _order, flag) as (
    select * from values
        (1, 10, 0),
        (1, 11, 0),
        (1, 12, 1),
        (1, 13, 0),
        (1, 14, 1),
        (1, 15, 0),
        (1, 16, 0),
        (1, 17, 1)
)
select 
    id
    ,_order
    ,flag
    ,iff(flag = 1, _order, null) as selector
    ,lead(selector)ignore nulls over(partition by id order by _order) as lead_select
    ,nvl(selector, lead_select ) as group_bucket
from data;
```

gives:

[image]

then to count on the buckets:

```
with data (id, _order, flag) as (
    select * from values
        (1, 10, 0),
        (1, 11, 0),
        (1, 12, 1),
        (1, 13, 0),
        (1, 14, 1),
        (1, 15, 0),
        (1, 16, 0),
        (1, 17, 1)
), grouped as (
    select 
        id
        ,_order
        ,flag
        ,iff(flag = 1, _order, null) as selector
        ,lead(selector)ignore nulls over(partition by id order by _order) as lead_select
        ,nvl(selector, lead_select ) as group_bucket
    from data
)
select
    id
    ,group_bucket as _order
    ,count(*)
from grouped
group by 1,2
order by 1,2
```

[image]

You could almost use a [conditional_change_event](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/conditional_change_event) and then divide by 2 and floor, but if the first event in an partition is the flag event, floor needs to be a ceil for the whole set, so I do not presently see a tidier way.

other than inline the grouping logic, but that makes it rather dense to read:

```
select 
    id
    ,_order
    ,flag
    ,nvl(iff(flag = 1, _order, null), lead(iff(flag = 1, _order, null))ignore nulls over(partition by id order by _order) ) as group_bucket
from data
```

Comment: Thanks @Simeon Pilgrim
i followed your script, thank you for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a session id for each group ending with a `new_entry_flg` of 1.

Classical SQL databases can be made to do this by a query that has a counter set to 1 every time a new group starts, from which an outer select creates a running sum. That's my `w_session` CTE below. I make sure I have no NULLs by wrapping the running sum expression in a `NVL()` function.

From that, I create the count of rows per partition of `userid` and the `session` that I created in the two previous CTEs, and finally filter by the very rows that have a 1 for `new_entry_flg`

```
WITH
-- your indata, enriched by a sequence number
-- table data is *never* ordered so we need that
indata(seq,userid,dt,wdow_name,new_entry_flg) AS (
          SELECT  1,'A',DATE '2023-03-07','index',0
UNION ALL SELECT  2,'A',DATE '2023-03-07','index',0
UNION ALL SELECT  3,'A',DATE '2023-03-07','index',0
UNION ALL SELECT  4,'A',DATE '2023-03-07','index',1
UNION ALL SELECT  5,'A',DATE '2023-03-07','index',0
UNION ALL SELECT  6,'A',DATE '2023-03-07','index',0
UNION ALL SELECT  7,'A',DATE '2023-03-17','index',1
UNION ALL SELECT  8,'B',DATE '2023-03-08','index',0
UNION ALL SELECT  9,'B',DATE '2023-03-09','index',0
UNION ALL SELECT 10,'B',DATE '2023-03-10','index',1
UNION ALL SELECT 11,'B',DATE '2023-03-11','index',0
UNION ALL SELECT 12,'B',DATE '2023-03-12','index',1
UNION ALL SELECT 13,'B',DATE '2023-03-13','index',1
)
-- real query starts here, replace following comma with "WITH"
,
-- need to sessionize - a session id for each group ending with new_entry_flg = 1
-- a) a counter
w_counter AS (
  SELECT 
    *
  , (LAG(new_entry_flg) OVER(PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY seq) = 1)::INTEGER AS session_start
  FROM indata
)
,
-- need to sessionize - a session id for each group ending with new_entry_flg = 1
-- b) the running sum of the counter
w_session AS (
  SELECT
    *
  , NVL(SUM(session_start) OVER(PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY seq),0) AS session
  FROM w_counter
)
,
-- 
w_rows_per_entry AS (
  SELECT
    *
  , COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY userid,session ORDER BY seq) AS rows_per_entry
  FROM w_session
)
SELECT
  userid
, dt
, wdow_name
, session + 1 AS entry_no
, rows_per_entry
FROM w_rows_per_entry
WHERE new_entry_flg=1
ORDER BY seq;
 userid |     dt     | wdow_name | entry_no | rows_per_entry 
--------+------------+-----------+----------+----------------
 A      | 2023-03-07 | index     |        1 |              4
 A      | 2023-03-17 | index     |        2 |              3
 B      | 2023-03-10 | index     |        1 |              3
 B      | 2023-03-12 | index     |        2 |              2
 B      | 2023-03-13 | index     |        3 |              1
```

Comment: Thanks @marcothesane , this is very clear and informative